# Laravel composer: Failed to load library

Tags: php, bash, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I get this error from my composer:

`Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so: /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.1.so: undefined symbol: zend_interrupt_function`

I already executed the command `composer update` but this problem still exists.. I don't even know where it is comming from or why I get it... I don't even get a proper error message.. How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

PHP Version: 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "zanysoft/laravel-zip": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    }
}
```

Kind regards

Comment: Can you post your `composer.json`

Comment: What is your PHP Version?

Comment: I have updated the question and added the informations!

Answer (score 0):

`Composer Update` will not help you to install ionCube.

The ionCube Loader is a PHP extension that enables PHP to execute files encoded using the ionCube Encoder.

Here is the detailed guide for installing ionCube on Ubuntu 16.04.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ioncube-on-ubuntu-16-04